# javascript - calling function with a return only returns string without parameter

Tags: javascript

Calling function with a return only returns string without a parameter. It only outputs "Hi, I am" what am i missing here. I have searched and searched...

```
var string = function nameString(name) {
return "Hi, I am" + " " +name;
};
string("casey");
console.log(nameString(name));
```

I have also wrote it like this.

```
function nameString(name){
return "Hi, I am" + " " + name ;
};
nameString("casey");
console.log(nameString(name));
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xvdvggha/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling it with a defined parameter, so it's not going to do anything.

Breaking down your example:

```
var string = function nameString(name) { // Declares a function nameString and assigns it to string
  return "Hi, I am" + " " +name;
};
string("casey"); // Calls string with name:"casey" but discards the return value
console.log(nameString(name)); // Calls nameString with the undefined global variable name
```

That's not going to work, since you end up returning `"Hi, I am " + undefined`.

What you probably want to do is call nameString and then save the return value, which is written:

```
function nameString(name) {
  return "Hi, I am" + " " +name;
};
var string = nameString("casey");
console.log(string );
```

Answer (score 2):

In the scope outside the function the variable 'name' is undefined. You have to define the variable first, than you can pass it as an argument to the function. This way:

```
function nameString(name){
return "Hi, I am" + " " + name ;
};

var name = "casey";
console.log(nameString(name));
```

If you are not too experienced, i suggest avoiding name conflicts in order to avoid confusion, so it would be better do this way :

```
function nameString(name){
return "Hi, I am" + " " + name ;
};

var exernalName= "casey";
console.log(nameString(externalName));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Syntax is off a bit.

```js
var string = function nameString(name) {
  return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;
};

alert(string("casey"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be a function expression or a function declaration so either:

```
var string = namestring() {}; // function expression
```

or

```
function nameString(name) {}; // function declaration
```

Your first one is both and that is why it doesn't work. To fix it you should just do:

```
function nameString(name) {
return "Hi, I am" + " " +name;
};

console.log(nameString("casey"));
```

Additionally I think what you were going for in your first attemp was something like this:

```
function nameString(name) {
  return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;
};

var string = nameString("casey"); // save this value to a var to use later

console.log(string); // use the "string" variable
```